# Is it possible to call a non static method in main?

Tags: java

I am trying to sum two numbers represented by linked lists. I have a problem with the static specifier and inner classes. I defined an inner class `SumWrapper` to keep track of the carry. I use this wrapper in my sum method. I first declared it as a static method, but I got the following error on Eclipse:

> No enclosing instance of type Solution is accessible. Must qualify the
>   allocation with an enclosing instance of type Solution (e.g. x.new A()
>   where x is an instance of Exo25V2).

I then removed the static specifier, but it makes it impossible to call my methods from main...

Is there a workaround?

```
public class Solution {

  public class SumWrapper{
    public int carry = 0;
    public Node node;

    public SumWrapper(int c, Node n){
      carry = c;
      node = n;
    }
  } // close sumWrapper class

  public SumWrapper sum(Node node1, Node node2){
    if (node1 == null && node2 == null){
      SumWrapper result = new SumWrapper(0, null);
      return result;
    }

    int current = node1.data + node2.data + sum(node1.next, node2.next).carry;
    int carry = (current >= 10) ? 1 : 0;
    current = current % 10;

    Node sumResult = new Node(current);
    sumResult.next = sum(node1.next, node2.next).node;

    SumWrapper result = new SumWrapper(carry, sumResult);

    return result;
  } // close sumWrapper method

  public int listSize(Node node){
    int result = 0;

    while (node != null){
      result++;
      node = node.next;
    }
    return result;
  } // close listSize method

  public Node sumLists(Node node1, Node node2){
    int size1 = listSize(node1);
    int size2 = listSize(node2);
    int size = (size1 >= size2) ? (size1+1):(size2+1);

    while (size1 < size){
      Node head1 = new Node(0);
      head1.next = node1;
      node1 = head1;
      size1++;
    }

    while (size2 < size){
      Node head2 = new Node(0);
      head2.next = node2;
      node2 = head2;
      size2++;
    }

    SumWrapper wrap = sum(node1, node2);

    return wrap.node;

  } // close sumLists method

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Node head1 = new Node(6);
    head1.appendToTail(1);
    head1.appendToTail(1);
    head1.appendToTail(7);

    Node head2 = new Node(2);
    head2.appendToTail(9);
    head2.appendToTail(5);

    Node result = sumLists(head1, head2);
    Node.printLinkedList(result);

  } // close main method
}
```

Comment: Is there an issue if you are declaring `sumLists` as static?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are invoking a non-static method (`sumLists`) from you `main` method. The `main` method is static and can therefore only access other static methods within the same class.

Unless... You create an instance of e.g. `Solution`:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Solution s = new Solution();
    s.sumLists(...); // now you invoke it using an instance method (i.e. a non-static method)
}
```

So, your options are:

1. Make your methods static.
2. Create an instance of the class and invoke the non-static methods.

For some good reading about this take a look at the [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 1):

In short NO, you cannot call any non-static method from inside a static method. Static method belongs to the class where as non-static method belongs to object.

You need to declare `SumWrapper` as static and all methods that you are being called from main.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the entire code to a different class altogether except the main() method. Then create an object of the class inside main() and access the method sumLists.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the `SumWrapper` class is not `static`. Non-static inner classes must be initialized from an instance of the outer class, so that they can have access to that instance. This is what the error you received is talking about.

But your `SumWrapper` class doesn't make use of its "parent" `Solution` object, so just make it static:

```
  public static class SumWrapper
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not declare the SumWrapper class as static?

It doesn't appear to require access to any state of an enclosing instance.

Answer (score 0):

it's allow when you're making an instance of some other object and call some method from this class

Answer (score 0):

You will have to either instantiate Solution and then call sumLists from the resulting object or declare sumLists and listSize as static.

Answer (score 0):

This is my general Scenario for solving a your problem.

```
   public class Customer {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Customer customer=new Customer();
customer.Business();
```

}

```
public static void Business(){
System.out.println("Hi Harry");
```

}
}